# Motivation behind the definition of Normal family of holomorphic functions?

Tags: complex-analysis

Following is copied from **Stein and Sakarchi'** Complex Analysis book:

Let $\Omega$ be an open subset of $\mathbb C$. A family $F$ of holomorphic functions on
$\Omega$ is said to be normal if every sequence in $F$ has a subsequence that
converges uniformly on every compact subset of $\Omega $ (the limit need not be
in $F$ ).

> What is the motivation of above definition? Why do we want to have subsequence on compact subset?

Comment: if a sequence $f_n$ of holomorphic (analytic) functions  converges compactly on $U$  (converges uniformly on any compact $K \subset U$) then the limit is holomorphic  on $U$

Comment: @user1952009: I am confused why do we always say just on compact subset of $U$ ?

Comment: for example $f(z) = 1/(z-1)$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{1\}$ (that is open) and its Taylor series at $z= 0$ converges uniformly to it on any compact $\subset \{|z| < 1\}$

Comment: @user1952009   Sorry..i was asking why dont we ask for uniform convergence everywhere as in real case?

Comment: That's what we do : everywhere on compact subsets of an open $U$. Take any example you'll get it is the only "topology" that makes sense in the context of holomorphic/analytic functions (and note how it implies the compact convergence of all the derivatives !!)

Comment: Sorry for troubling you..but i will be happy if you will explain bit more about 'it is the only topology that make sense in the context of holomorphic functions'?

Comment: I said everything. [$f_n \to f$ compactly on $U$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_convergence) where the $f_n$ are holomorphic on $U$ means that $f$ is holomorphic on $U$ and that $f_n' \to f'$ compactly on $U$ as all the other derivatives. Now try with an example, you'll see the uniform convergence is true only on some compact subsets but not on the whole domain of convergence

Comment: @user1952009:thank you i'll try examples.

Comment: "i was asking why dont we ask for uniform convergence everywhere as in real case?" It's not something you run into very often when you take a walk in the woods.

Comment: @zhw.: Could you please elaborate your comment and write a answer of this question? Thank you.